# jquery live condition not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, live

I'm using jquery, in normal condition `$(document).ready` row and column in table is highlighted. but when I call data with table to using `$.ajax({})`, rows and columns not highlighted.

my code simply like this

```
$('table td').hover( function() {
     $(this).css('background-color','white'); 
     $(this).siblings().css('background','#F0F8FF'); 
     var ind = $(this).index(); 
     $('table td:nth-child('+(ind+1)+')').css('background','#F0F8FF');
}, function() { 
     $('table td').css('background','white');
}).click( function() { 
     $(this).css("background","#9DFF9D");
});
```

is there anyone know the solutions..?

**in live code**

```
$('table td').live("hover",function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','white');
        $(this).siblings().css('background','#F0F8FF');
        var ind = $(this).index();
        $('table td:nth-child('+(ind+1)+')').css('background','#F0F8FF');
    });
```

**I found the solution**

i create the function like this

```
function HighlightTable(){
    //table hover column & row highlight    
    $('table td').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','white');
        $(this).siblings().css('background','#F0F8FF');
        var ind = $(this).index();
        $('table td:nth-child('+(ind+1)+')').css('background','#F0F8FF');
    },function(){
        $('table td').css('background','white');
    }).click(function(){$(this).css("background","#9DFF9D");});
}
```

when `$.ajax` called then use the `HighlightTable()` `onsuccess` condition

```
$.ajax({
   url:'something.php'
   success: function(data){
      $('div').html(data); HighlightTable();
   }
})
```

thats all, thankyou guys

Comment: use $('table td').live("hover", function() {

Comment: live condition is like this `$('table td').live("mouseenter",function() {
  $(this).css('background-color','white');
  $(this).siblings().css('background','#F0F8FF');
  var ind = $(this).index();
  $('table td:nth-child('+(ind+1)+')').css('background','#F0F8FF');
 });` but the result not as expectation

Comment: @jinSun table structure is required if you are able to post, post it at your post.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use `.on()` and `event delegation` to `closest existing parent` or `document` itself.

```
$(document).on('hover', 'table td', function() {
     $(this).css('background-color','white'); 
     $(this).siblings().css('background','#F0F8FF'); 
     var ind = $(this).index(); 
     $('table td:nth-child('+Math.floor(ind+1)+')').css('background','#F0F8FF');
 }, function() { 
     $('table td').css('background','white');
 }).click( function() { 
     $(this).css("background","#9DFF9D");
 });
```

Comment: i've tried your code, the result no rows and columns is highlighted, any else..?

Comment: can you give your table structure plz?

Comment: To start with, I suggest you use @JinSun answer but then again, I don't think the problem is based on this. Can you update your question to include the HTML you have?

Comment: Also, be consistent! If you use background-color, use it in your remaining code as well. Don't use background-color in your second line and use background in the other lines.

Answer (score 0):

I see no `.live()` and also first you use `background-color` and in the remaining you use only `background`.. Can that be the problem?

Comment: `$('table td').live("mouseenter",function() {
  $(this).css('background-color','white');
  $(this).siblings().css('background','#F0F8FF');
  var ind = $(this).index();
  $('table td:nth-child('+(ind+1)+')').css('background','#F0F8FF');
 });` the row and column is highlited but not good

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table td').on("hover",function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','white');
    $(this).siblings().css('background','#F0F8FF');
    var ind = $(this).index();
    $('table td:nth-child('+(ind+1)+')').css('background','#F0F8FF');
});
```

Check this code.

Comment: check my edited code , you want change color of td on hover right ?

Comment: @DevangRathod it looks pretty promising but do u know jQuery supports "hover" for live(), on() events only with one event handler function...???

Comment: yes i do that too, but still not good as expextatioin, because it is different before live condition

Answer (score 0):

`.hover()` has it's own handler: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

If you want to do multiple things, chain them in the `.on()` handler like so:

```
$(document).on(
{
    mouseenter: function() 
    {
        //stuff to do on mouseover
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        //stuff to do on mouseleave
    }
}
, '.selector'); //pass the element as an argument to .on
```

jQuery supports "hover" for `live()` events, but only with one event handler function:

```
$("document").live("hover",
     function()
     {

     }
);
```

so alternatively, you can provide two functions, one for mouseenter and one for mouseleave as i wrote in above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on({ 
    mouseenter: 
       function() 
       { 
       $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
       $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '#F0F8FF');
       var ind = $(this).index();
       $('table td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').css('background-color', '#F0F8FF');
       }, 
    mouseleave: 
       function() 
       { 
       $('table td').css('background-color', 'white');
       } ,
    click:
       function() 
       { 
        $(this).css("background-color", "#9DFF9D");
       } ,
   }, "table td"
);
```

See sample http://jsfiddle.net/7pvpJ/

Comment: not a bad idea, but still not as expectation. still different when not live condition

Comment: @JinSun : Why are you calling `HighlightTable()` function..???!!! The hover and click events just need to be inside `$(document).ready({});`... no need of a function like what you have in your sample code...

Comment: i;ve do it before, but its not working. my method is working and nice. you should try it